# PHP detect and store returning emails

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm sending some newletters using PHP mail() with a Sender address.

For some reasons that I will have to check, many of these newlsetters are bounced and return a "failure notice" to my Sender address.

At the moment these emails are simply returned to the email client where we read the emails of the Sender.

I wish I could store and manage all these "failed" email addresses for my marketing staff.
Of course it is very hard to copy/paste each email address from the email client (they are hundreds).

Is there a way to detect and catch via PHP these addresses to be stored in a Mysql table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on what you use as a mail server, please add details. There are always options, like PHP has IMAP code to open and read IMAP mailboxes - you can write something to do that and put the emails into a MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the information about failed messages from the `mail()` command as this only sands the message to your local mail server for handling.

You will need to implement a cronjob or otherwise regularly called script that will check the mailbox. So you will need to use the [IMAP and POP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) in PHP to fetch the messages and process failed messages.

Or you will need to check the manual for your mail-server to check if you can include some code to execute when the server encounters a failure. So the mailserver itself will flag the failed messages inside your database or at least calls a script providing it with the failed message.

Answer (score 0):

The customary solution to this is VERP http://cr.yp.to/proto/verp.txt -- basically, use a unique envelope sender for each message; anything sent back to that particular address is a bounce, from the address you tried to send to.

For example, if your list is called `fnord@example.org` and you send message 12345 to `djb@example.net.invalid` then the envelope sender for that message would be something like `fnord-12345-djb=example.net.invalid@example.org` and your MTA should be configured to route any email to this address to the correct place (a script to remove the failed address from your database, or whatever).

Of course, if you use a proper mailing list manager (and you should!), it will already contain the logic to take care of all of this; it should be a simple matter of configuration.